# Error correction : The fact that the compact car is better than conventional cars has been proved by its sales

Tags: articles, exam-questions

> The fact that the compact car (A)/ is better than (B)/ conventional cars has(C)/ been proved by its sales.(D)

In part C of the sentence *the* hasn't been used which I think is correct but isn't the *the* used in part A of sentence incorrect ? I guess the correct sentence should read *The fact that compact car is better than conventional cars has been proved by its sales.* or is part A correct and we need to correct part C by inserting *the* before conventional cars ?

Comment: They might be looking for *been prov**en***.

Comment: There is nothing ungrammatical about the sentence. Any improvements would be stylistic, e.g. eliminating "the fact", or changing "conventional cars" to "the conventional car", or making "Its sales" the subject and recasting in the active voice.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo But why 'the' is used with compact cars not with conventional cars ? Isn't it better to use it with both or none ? Why use it with just one ?

Comment: There are several ways to refer to a noun generically. You can refer to the noun as a representative of its class or type by using the definite article (**the compact car** is better than **the conventional sedan**) or by using the plural to refer to the class in terms of all of the members it contains,  (**compact cars** are better than **conventional sedans**), or by referring to an anonymous unspecified single instance (**a compact car** is better than **a conventional sedan**).

Comment: And there is no grammatical rule that *requires* the generic comparands to be specified using the same form of the generic. You could say "On unpaved roads the SUV is better than a compact car." Stylistically it would be an improvement to use the same form: "On unpaved roads an SUV is better than a compact car".